# Bloques de inicialización en Java

Tags: java

Qué tal? Hace poco comencé a estudiar Java y se me presentó una duda: estaba viendo que los bloques de inicialización se ejecutan antes que los constructores, por lo que entendi que son útiles para inicializar atributos, sean del contexto estático o dinámico, pero hasta ahora lo que precisamente empleaba para inicializar atributos de la clase, eran los constructores. En ese sentido, cuál es la diferencia? Qué otras funciones pueden tener los constructores aparte de inicializar objetos?

Comment: Las preguntas basaas en opiniones suelen ser cerradas.

Comment: No entiendo, disculpá

Comment: No soy experto en Java, pero tu pregunta parece que va a ocasionar respuestas basadas en opiniones, algo que el sitio no permite, por lo tanto, tu pregunta podría cerrarse sin respuesta alguna. Dicúlpa mi anterior comentario, tiendo a resumir tanto que hay veces que no se entiende, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido por el sitio que aclara estos conceptos.

Comment: Pero en caso de que dos herramientas puedan hacer, en principio, lo mismo, como en este caso entiendo que hace el constructor y los bloques de inicialización, de qué otra forma podría resolver mi duda si no es con una opinión? Antes de hacer el posteo me sugirió un post que habla sobre los bloques, pero mi cuestión parte de la similitud que le encuentro al constructor y a los bloques. Gracias por responder!

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente y de hecho, yo mismo he visto en el sitio preguntas y respuestas aceptadas que son opiniones, tal vez no tengo yo el concepto claro, de todas formas por eso no te he votado negativo, porque tengo dudas. Deja la pregunta y que otro se promulgue al respecto. O plantéala para que no se trate de opiniones, por ejemplo, cambiando dónde dices "qué es más conveniente?" por "¿cúal es la diferencia?".

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

> cuál es la diferencia?

No hay ninguna diferencia. La inicialización de la variable de instancia se coloca en el constructor cuando se compila el código. Pasa a ser una cuestión de gustos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si la respuesta contestó tu pregunta, considera marcarla como aceptada. Saludos